# How can I test if a class instance belongs to one of the parent classes that are on the same level?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, interface, extends

Say I have this:

```
class Bird{}
class PrettyBird extends Bird{}
class UglyBird extends Bird{}
class Duckling extends UglyBird{}
```

and I do this:

```
$bird = new Duckling();
```

OR

```
$bird = new UglyBird();
```

Suppose in my universe all I am interested in is if class belongs to `UglyBird` or `PrettyBird`.  In case above, I want to test whether `$bird` belongs to `UglyBird` (super)class in both cases above.

How?

Currently I can do it by

```
if (get_class($bird) === UglyBird::class 
    or get_class($bird) === Duckling::class)
    print "MATCH!";
```

but that's impractical.  For example, what if I create a new class that extends `UglyBird`.  I will have to add that class into the `if` statement.

Comment: i would hope that when writing this you would know and not need to detect it via code.

Comment: did you try `instanceof ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instanceof` operator for this check:

```
if ($bird instanceof UglyBird) {
    print "MATCH!";
}
```

It will work for instances of UglyBird and all inherited classes

Check documentation for details: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [is_subclass_of](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php):

```
$bird = new Duckling();
$bird2 = new PrettyBird();

var_dump(is_subclass_of($bird, 'UglyBird')); // True
var_dump(is_subclass_of($bird2, 'UglyBird')); // False
```

Suppose you have a child class of `PrettyBird`:

```
class PrettyDuckling extends PrettyBird{}
```

And you want to know if the child of PrettyBird is a subclass of UglyBird:

```
$bird3 = new PrettyDuckling();
var_dump(is_subclass_of($bird3, 'PrettyBird')); // True
var_dump(is_subclass_of($bird3, 'UglyBird')); // False
```

Note that this will work for the parent of the parent as well:

```
var_dump(is_subclass_of($bird, 'Bird')); // True
var_dump(is_subclass_of($bird2, 'Bird')); // True
var_dump(is_subclass_of($bird3, 'Bird')); // True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`get_parent_class` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php):

```
class Bird{}
class PrettyBird extends Bird{}
class UglyBird extends Bird{}
class Duckling extends UglyBird{}

$bird = new Duckling();
var_dump(get_parent_class($bird));
$bird = new UglyBird();
var_dump(get_parent_class($bird));
```

Output:

```
string(8) "UglyBird"
string(4) "Bird"
```

You can check:

```
if (get_parent_class(new Duckling()) == get_parent_class(new UglyBird())) {
    ....
}
```